# Allow creating a list of questions, establishing a curated team FAQ

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Starting Stack Overflow for Teams trial was a no-brainer today and we already have the first accepted Q&A pair. In order to seed the site with useful content, we will be migrating some internal Q&A texts.

However, that immediately spawns a concern regarding findability of vital information that is valid long-term and is useful for newcomers, to help solve infrequent but repeated problems faster etc. Hence I'd like to propose that SO for Teams would include a feature that would enable teams to curate a shortlist of such key Q&A. Here are some options how this could work:

#### (1) Per-tag pinned questions

Users could pin questions that are generally useful. Think of this as “shared favorites”. A list of pinned questions would appear on the tag page.

*Note: I am aware of the “frequent” tab. However, pinned questions would result in a static list rather a dynamic, giving teams a chance to highlight what's important for them on their terms.*

#### (2) Custom FAQ lists

Provide an ability to define custom FAQs, with lists of such questions. This feature could provide just a single FAQ page, with categories based on the primary tags.

#### (3) Custom markdown wiki pages

Also, a basic markdown page could work, too, leading to a simple team wiki feature.

Comment: Pity teams is a private thing, I'd have liked to see this historic accepted Q&A you mentioned :-(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think for a private group it makes more sense, as the volume of the questions will be significantly lower (and in a large organization a curation team can be set up). On the public SO, there just “a few” very important questions, like [everyone's favorite NullReferenceException question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/245183).

Comment: I'm not fond of the "custom markdown wiki pages" idea. You already *have* that. They're called questions. I don't think Teams should try to be a general documentation tool; SO's strength is its Q&A approach. (E.g., Documentation never took off.) If you're looking for a general wiki... have a general wiki alongside the Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

I'm genuinely not sure if this is *quite* the same thing - or whether most of this speaks only to your first bullet point ("Per-tag pinned questions"), but you do have full access to the usual tag wiki functionality, which can be used to curate such a tome, including full context in whatever way works for you, rather than just a naked list of questions; this is similar to how tag wikis are often used on Stack Overflow, for example [here's C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info). Maybe we could make this more discoverable, if it wasn't obvious?

---

What perhaps is even more subtle: by default, teams actually *inherit* the wiki for tags that they've used - for example, if they use `java` as a tag, the **Stack Overflow** `java` wiki will be displayed *unless* you go in and edit it, in which case you're editing your own private copy. This is to help when you have your own internal system called "sometool" or whatever, that is unrelated to the regular term - or you just want a wiki that is more specific to how *you* use it in your team. We don't have an official vocabulary for this, but: we track it and display those tags differently, so you can see which are "your" tags.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* leverage the normal tagging system to accomplish much of this.

1. Create an `[faq]` tag.
2. Now users can search by this tag for common questions.
3. They can narrow the search by adding addition tags, giving you your per tag FAQ.

This doesn't give you your FAQ dashboard showing all the questions, though. Does Teams support JS snippets? If so, you could post a question containing one that could be run to generate the dashboard. Hacky and a little clunky, but would get the job done in the mean time.

To be entirely honest, I'm not sold on the usefulness of an FAQ dashboard, though. Searching for questions seems far more useful.